# Short clarification regarding Vector spaces/subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose    is a subset of a vector space $V$. To determine if *W* is a subspace of *V* , it is sufficient to determine if the following 3 conditions hold, using the operations of *V* :

1. The additive identity  $0$   of *V*  is contained in *W* .
2. For any vectors  $w_1$, $w_2$  in   , $w_1+w_2$  is also in $W$ .
3. For any vector  $w$  in    and scalar   , the product  $aw$  is also in $W$

My question: Isnt first condition redundant due to third one... we can take scalar $a=0$ so that $0$ vector will always be in $W$ ?

Comment: if $W$ is non-empty, then sure, $(3)$ implies $(1)$. But $(1)$ is there to ensure the non-emptiness.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Are you saying (1) is there only for the case when $W=\phi$?

Comment: yes, vector spaces by definition are non-empty (they must contain a $0$ element), so it is completely equivalent to replace (1) by (1'): "$W$ is non-empty ($W\neq \emptyset$)".

Comment: @peek-a-boo That sounds like an answer, not a comment.